# Number of solutions of $x^2+y^2=1 \mod p^2$ with prime $p=3\mod 4$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am asked to find the number of solutions of $x^2+y^2=1 \mod p^2$, with $p=3 \mod 4$ prime.
I thought a possible way was to apply Hensel's lemma, to shift the $\mod p$ solutions to $\mod p^2$ solutions, but I am not able to conclude my argument. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know how many solutions there are (mod $p$), to start?

Comment: how many solutions mod $p \; ? \;$

Comment: What have you tried? The lifting seems straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have $ x^2 + y^2 = -1 \pmod{p}$.
We want to lift it to a solution, namely:

$$ -1 \equiv (x+k_y p)^2 + (y+k_yp)^2 \equiv x^2 + y^2 + 2(k_xx + k_yy)p \pmod{p^2}.$$

This happens when $k_x + k_y = A$ (for you to determine).
Hence, with every initial solution in mod $p$, there are $B$ (for you to determine) solutions in mod $p^2$.

Comment: Since we start from $x^2+y^2=1 \mod p$, I think the lifting provides $1\equiv (x+k_x p)^2+(y+k_y p)^2\equiv x^2+y^2+2p(k_x x + k_y y)\mod p^2$; am I wrong?
But then how can I continue?

Comment: @Stan Oh yes, you're right about the calculation. How can you continue? What condition needs to be satisfied?

Comment: Well, you want $ 2(k_x x + ky y)\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ as the condition right? So if $ p\neq 2, xy\neq 0$, then how many solutions can do you get?